# Unable to rake db:structure:load due to permissions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm just trying to set up PostgreSQL 9.5 for Rails Application. Firstly I did

```
$ createdb mydb
$ psql mydb
$ CREATE USER zip
$ grant all privileges on database mydb to zip;
$ CREATE ROLE zip superuser
$ GRANT ROOT TO zip
$ ALTER ROLE zip WITH LOGIN
$ CREATE ROLE zip superuser createdb login;
$ createdb zipzav_test
```

I went out of psql with`\q` and ran

```
$ rake db:structure:load 

psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "zip"
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
psql -q -f /home/faisal/Developer/Myapp/db/structure.sql mydb
```

Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `psql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.

```
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:90:in `run_cmd'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:62:in `structure_load'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:188:in `structure_load'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:221:in `load_schema_for'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:235:in `block in load_schema_current'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:234:in `load_schema_current'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:293:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/faisal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: @Deepak I believe that psql is installed. Not sure how to check the permissions. I'm using Fedora 25

Comment: when is zipzav going live?